# Editing and updating address in profile creates a new address

Tags: login

Steps to create:
1. Log in to account.
2. Go to profile and select edit existing address
3. deselect country and update.
4. Observer error message will be displayed and state, city field are blank.
5. change the pincode, check state and city fields takes values.
6. click on update.
7. Observe a new address is created

Is this is default feature? how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This is not default functionality as far as I have tested in Magento 1.9.

I would suggest that you have some custom code in place that is breaking the flow somewhere.